# Is there any advantage or disadvantage of using javascript over solidity when building dapps on etherum?

Tags: solidity, dapps, javascript, dapp-development

I am aware that there are libraries that let you build dapps on ethereum. What are the pros and cons of using javascript over solidity for dapps. I know this might sound like a partly subjective question but sometime that is what you need to give you perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both.

You use Solidity for the contract, or Vyper less commonly.

You also usually need front-end and possibly server interactions. Those are usually but not necessarily JavaScript.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand i need javascript. I understand the basics of coding. I develop web apps. What I do not understand is [this](https://medium.com/oli-systems/building-dapps-backend-with-node-js-and-webpack-311cda224da5). That article says you can use javascript. Does it just use libraries that talk with solidity code? And Do you loose any functionality by using javascript?

Comment: Actually I think I understand now. They are libraries(the javascript part) that help with interacting with the ethereum blockchain. Thank you.